# Running an animation when text is changed of TextBlock in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, animation, data-binding, mvvm

I am making an WPF application following MVVM pattern. I have one button and textblock. TextBlock is only shown when its text is not empty. On start of application text is empty to textblock is not shown. When i click button sample text is set and textblock is shown. And when i click again button text is set to empty and textblock hides.

Now what I want is that when text is set there start animation (fading) opacity changes from 0 to 1 in 5 seconds.

Here is my XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusMessage}" Visibility="{Binding IsStatusMessageVisible}" />
<Button Content="UpdateText" Command="{Binding UpdateTextCommand}" />
```

And here is my ViewModel.

```
    private string _statusMessage;
    public string StatusMessage
    {
        get { return _statusMessage ?? (_statusMessage = string.Empty); }
        set
        {
            _statusMessage = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsStatusMessageVisible);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => StatusMessage);
        }
    }

    public System.Windows.Visibility IsStatusMessageVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StatusMessage))
                ? System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
                : System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateText()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StatusMessage))
            StatusMessage = Properties.Resources.WaitMessageStatus;
        else
            StatusMessage = string.empty;
    }
```

I just want that when StatusMessage text is set animation runs.

Comment: And what's the problem you actually have with your code?

Comment: @ken2k this code works fine. I need to add animation in this code. When some text is added to StatusMessage textblock is shown. I want that there is some animation (fading) when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. declare a TextChanged event in your ViewModel
2. in the set method of your StatusMessage property, before the line "_statusMessage = value;" raise your TextChanged event if (_statusMessage != value && !string.IsNulOrEmpty(value));
3. in your XAML, create a StoryBoard to change the opacity of the TextBlock
4. in you XAML, add a ControlStoryBoardBehavior to the TextBlock, and select your TextChanged event and your StoryBoard

Comment: i haven't worked on storyboards. can you give me the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the "Visibility" property on your ViewModel, that doesn't belong there...it should be a boolean. Then, create a style for your `TextBlock`. In that style, add `DataTrigger` to bind to the boolean "IsVisible" property. Inside the `DataTrigger`, create a storyboard:

```
<DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <!--Animation code in here /-->
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</DataTrigger.EnterActions>
```

For an example of how to do opacity animation, just Google it...but here's [one way](http://tarundotnet.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/wpf-tutorial-change-opacity-using-animation/)

Answer (score 0):

One way to run an animation on a `TextChanged` in a `TextBlock` is the following:

```
 <TextBlock
        Text="{Binding MyText, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                            From="0.0"
                            To="1.0"
                            Duration="0:0:0.300" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
```

NB: This code is only for learning purposes: the animation itself is not very useful or nice.